# Error creating samples with mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(size_upms = c(126, 123, 148),
             electric_mean = c(0.716756756756757,0.647859922178988, 0.726313694267516),
             gas_mean = c(0.273513513513513,0.322679266259033, 0.259554140127389),
             firewood_mean = c(0, 0.00111172873818788,0.00179140127388535))

# df
#  size_upms electric_mean  gas_mean firewood_mean
#1       126     0.7167568 0.2735135   0.000000000
#2       123     0.6478599 0.3226793   0.001111729
#3       148     0.7263137 0.2595541   0.001791401
```

I want to obtain samples using parameters for each row using mapply

```
l <- mapply(sample,c("electric","gas","firewood"),df$size_upms,TRUE,
            c(df$electric_mean,df$gas_mean,df$firewood_mean))
```

But I get this error:

```
#Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
#  too few positive probabilities
```

However if I apply sample function to each row, it works:

```
sample(c("electric","gas","firewood"),df$size_upms[1],TRUE,
   c(df$electric_mean[1],df$gas_mean[1],df$firewood_mean[1]))[1:5]
#[1] "gas"      "electric" "electric" "gas"      "electric"
sample(c("electric","gas","firewood"),df$size_upms[2],TRUE,
   c(df$electric_mean[2],df$gas_mean[1],df$firewood_mean[2]))[1:5]
#[1] "electric" "gas"      "gas"      "gas"      "electric"
sample(c("electric","gas","firewood"),df$size_upms[3],TRUE,
   c(df$electric_mean[3],df$gas_mean[3],df$firewood_mean[1]))[1:5]
#[1] "electric" "electric" "gas"      "electric" "electric"
```

But I want to use mapply because I want to apply it to a big dataframe

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is by rows, it is easier to do with `apply` or `lapply`.  There won't much difference in performance between `mapply` or other `apply` solutions

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) 
    sample(c("electric","gas","firewood"), df$size_upms[i], TRUE, 
    unlist(c(df$electric_mean[i],df$gas_mean[i],df$firewood_mean[i]))))
```

---

The error in OP's solution is the concatenation process.  Here, we pass the arguments as separate columns from the dataset and then in the anonymous function call, do the concatenation.  This will make sure that for each step, the corresponding row element from the column is selected.

```
Map(function(x,y, u, w) sample(c("electric","gas","firewood"), x, 
     TRUE, c(y, u, w)), df$size_upms, df$electric_mean, df$gas_mean, df$firewood_mean)
```

Or as @thelatemail commented, we can avoid some typing by using `do.call`

```
do.call(Map, c( function(x,y, u, w) 
    sample(c("electric","gas","firewood"), x, TRUE, c(y,u,w)), unname(df)))
```

Comment: The `Map` solution is neatest I reckon.

Comment: You could even save a bit of typing like `do.call(Map, c( function(x,y, u, w) sample(c("electric","gas","firewood"), x, TRUE, c(y,u,w)), unname(df) ))`

Comment: Awesome, thaks for the very detailled explanation @akrun

Comment: In Map, x argument is corresponding to?

Comment: @Israel, The anonymous function call arguments corresponds to each of the input arguments in Map. i.e. 'x' would be 'df$size_upms'

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun